# Subclass not inheriting parent class fields

Tags: java, inheritance, subclass

I have a subclass but the problem is that for some reason, it doesn't inherit the main class' fields. I've tried making the public instead of private (even though you're supposed to be able to access private fields from subclasses anyway) but even that didn't work.

```
package com.testfoler;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Fenetre extends JFrame {

    private Panneau pan = new Panneau();
    public JButton bouton = new JButton("Go");
    public JButton bouton2 = new JButton("Stop");
    private JPanel container = new JPanel();
    private JLabel label = new JLabel("Le JLabel");

    public Fenetre() {
        this.setTitle("Animation");
        this.setSize(300, 300);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

        container.setBackground(Color.white);
        container.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        container.add(pan, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        bouton.addActionListener(new BoutonListener());
        bouton.setEnabled(false);
        bouton2.addActionListener(new Bouton2Listener());

        JPanel south = new JPanel();
        south.add(bouton);
        south.add(bouton2);
        container.add(south, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        Font police = new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 16);
        label.setFont(police);
        label.setForeground(Color.blue);
        label.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
        container.add(label, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        this.setContentPane(container);
        this.setVisible(true);
    }
}

// Those are the subclasses
class BoutonListener implements ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
        bouton.setEnabled(false);
        bouton2.setEnabled(true);
    }
}

class Bouton2Listener implements ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        bouton.setEnabled(true);
        bouton2.setEnabled(false);
    }
}
```

Comment: A subclass *cannot* access a `private` member of a superclass.

Comment: no, that's not it. I tried making them public too.

Comment: you'd better post the code of your *subclass* and *superclass* for us.

Comment: The classes you have introduced as subclasses are not subclasses. They are inner classes. They don't inherit from the enclosing class, but they do have access to all its members, *including* the private ones. Unclear what your problem is, if any, or what you're asking.

Comment: @EJP I know i didn't use the right term. Cause i'm learning Java in french so I had to translate it the best I could.

Comment: If you didn't mean 'subclass', asking a question about why they don't inherit anything is meaningless and pointless. They do inherit, but from their parent class, which in this case is `java.lang.Object.` It remains entirely unclear what this question is actually about. You didn't for example provide a compilation error to back up your claim.

Comment: @EJP no but the question has been answered already. I'll take that in consideration next time

Comment: I'm still trying to find out what the question actually is. If 'subclass' is just a mistranslation there is no inheritance to ask about, and as your code compiles it is unclear why you're even asking a question at all.

Comment: the code did not compile. that was the problem. Eclipse was telling me that it didn't recognize the the 2 JButtons that I referenced in the the 2 inner classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You marked the fields as private, thus they cannot be inherited.

Futhermore, these "subclasses" don't extend your Fenetre class. Pay attention.

Should be:

```
class BoutonListener extends Fenetre implements ActionListener
```

instead of:

```
class BoutonListener implements ActionListener
```

in both cases.

Comment: @Zerox029 Edited my answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
//Those are the subclasses 
class BoutonListener implements ActionListener{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
       bouton.setEnabled(false);
       bouton2.setEnabled(true);
   }
}
```

Your 'subclasses' don't extend any superclass. They are not subclasses of `Fenetre`.